# How to slice a string as utf8 in rust

Tags: string, rust, utf-8

I am writing a rust toy parser, and I want to handle UTF-8 char in my string input. I knew that I need to use `chars` method to get UTF-8 iterator to correctly get a UTF-8 char, but I want to slice string using UTF-8 index. Is there any method I can use ? I looked into SWC, but I couldn't understand how it handles UTF-8 strings because it seems the input api needs to develop self to handle correct UFT-8 index.

```rs
use swc_common::input::{StringInput, Input};
use swc_common::BytePos;
fn main() {
    let utf8_str = "中文字串";
    let mut input =  StringInput::new("中文字串", BytePos(0), BytePos(utf8_str.len().try_into().unwrap()));
    println!("{:?}", input.slice(BytePos(0), BytePos(3)));
    println!("{:?}", &utf8_str[0..3]);
   // is there any function like slice(start_usize, end_usize) can get utf-8 string 
}
```

Comment: Your code using slicing syntax works, what is your issue with it?

Comment: Hi @cafce25, I would like to slice UTF-8 string using UTF-8 index, not byte index, above example I use byte index. so I need to know current byte is 8bit or more bit, but I want to be able to index string like `slice(0, 2)` and get first 2 UTF-8 char like call twice `next` method of the iterator

Comment: This is impossible to do in `O(1)` since UTF-8 characters have variable sizes. You can do it in `O(n)` using [`char_indices().nth (n)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.char_indices) to get the byte index of the start position of the `n`th character.

Comment: Would it be a significant overhead to use a Vec<char> (utf-32) rather than rust strings? That is the usual answer for if you need O(1) access to slice codepoints. If you need to slice graphemes, then that's a whole other problem, and probably best solved by using a lexer.

Answer (score 1):

Slicing with character indices is not supported and since the `SliceIndex` trait is sealed you can't implement it. But you can use [`char_indices`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.char_indices) to calculate the corresponding byte indices for every utf8 character:

```rust
fn main() {
    let utf8_str = "中文字串";
    let start_char = 1;
    let end_char = 2;
    let mut indices = utf8_str.char_indices().map(|(i, _)| i);
    let start = indices.nth(start_char).unwrap();
    let end = indices.nth(end_char - start_char - 1).unwrap_or(utf8_str.len());
    println!("{:?}", &utf8_str[start..end]);
}
```

output:

```
"文"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what if I am not want start with first index  like slice(2,4) it there any method I can use to generate iterate from n UTF8 index ?

Comment: You just calculate that index as well. `let start = utf8_str.char_indices().nth(2).unwrap().0;` with a little bit of maths you can reuse that iterator, too.

Comment: Thanks but the time complexity of this method would be O(n) right ?

Comment: As [noted by Jmb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76754171/how-to-slice-a-string-has-utf8-in-rust/76754489?noredirect=1#comment135315953_76754171) indexing by character offset in utf8 is impossible in `O(1)`, there is no better performance than `O(n)` because you have to look at all the chars before to know the byte offset.

Comment: @steven-lie ...other than specialized data structures that do have O(1) char access.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman What datastructures would be preferable that allow arbitrary O(1) access to utf-8 chars, and don't have more overhead than just storing the string in utf-32 format (Vec<char>)?